# python sql fetchone without poping it off.

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

How can I use the python fetchone() call without removing it from the list.

If I do:

```
while True:
    print cur.fetchone()
```

where each line is the next row.

How can I do something like

```
cur.fetchone(pop=False) # so it doesnt remove it from the list as Im just testing something and I will actually fetch that row later.
```

basically. I need to fetch a row. Check something in it. if it matches, pop if off the list and do stuff to that row. Otherwise. move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. While @Martijn Pieters is correct and there is no "popless" fetch. Here is a work around.

```
        try:
            oldwork = 1
            work = 1
            workingset = []
            HasStuff = True
            while HasStuff:
                result = cur.fetchone()
                if result is not None:
                    work = result[0]
                    if work == oldwork:
                        workingset.append(result)
                    else:
                        cleanDataSet(workingset)
                        workingset = []
                        workingset.append(result)
                    oldwork = work
                else:
                    cleanDataSet(workingset)
                    workingset = []
                    HasStuff = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Just store the return value first:

```
while True:
    result = cur.fetchone()
    if result is not None:
        # do something.
```